# Generate pivotitem dynamically?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, pivotitem

```
 private void myPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime nextDate;
        if ((myPivot.SelectedIndex) == (myPivot.Items.Count() - 1))
        {
           nextDate = DateTime.ParseExact((myPivot.SelectedItem as PivotItem).Tag.ToString(),"dd'/'MM'/'yy", null);
           PivotItem pItem = new PivotItem();
           pItem.Header = (nextDate.AddDays(1).Day.ToString()) + "/" + (nextDate.AddDays(1).Month.ToString()) + " - " + (nextDate.AddDays(7).Day.ToString()) + "/" + (nextDate.AddDays(7).Month.ToString());
           pItem.Tag = nextDate.AddDays(7).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
           myPivot.Items.Add(pItem);


        } 
    }
```

Hi all, 
Having an issue with the dynamically generated pivotitem. In the above selectionchanged event, on each swipe to the right, it generates a pivot item automatically, but the only problem is that the generated item doesn't seem to highlight, the selected pivot item has a grayed out header. Is there any additional line that I need to add to get that working?

Comment: What kind of project is this in?

Comment: Trying to create Scheduler app.

Comment: I meant what language? Desktop/web? C#/Java? etc.

Comment: C#, developing for windows phone.